# Raw copy external drives

Tags: external-hdd

I have one ***almost full*** external HDD with ***1TB***, and the other ***empty*** with ***2TB***.

What is ***the fastest way to copy*** the content from the smaller to the bigger? Is there a way to do some kind of ***raw*** copy without skipping the blocks/sectors, just continuous copying?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use command prompt with `cp` command.

So you have to mount *2nd* HDD and run this command:

```
cp -R source/* destination
```

Hope you can understand from this short description. Reply for further assistance..

[cp command tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/cp.htm)

[cp command tutorial 2](http://www.basicconfig.com/linux/how_to_copy_files_directory_linux)

Comment: Are you sure it will do the >>raw<< copying, block/sector per block/sector and not instead file per file. And file can be fragmented.

Comment: Since your 2nd HDD is fully empty and obviously defragmented, I hope so. I'm attaching a link which is a good tutorial of CP command! Just give it a look..

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think that `dd` command is what I've been looking for.